# Указывается неверный вывод lenght() при укорачивании string

Tags: c++, строки

Проблема заключается в том, что при укорачивании строки в коде, то есть после удаления пробелов длина массива, выдаваемая lenght остается неизменной.
Вопрос в том, обязательно ли создавать новый массив, либо можно как-то укоротить его изначальный размер?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;
int YANEXOTEL;

string np(string slovo)
    {
    int dlina = slovo.length();

    for (int i = 0; i != dlina - 1; i++)
    {
        if (slovo[i] == ' ')
        {
            for (auto symb = i; symb != dlina; symb++)
            {
                slovo[symb] = slovo[symb + 1];
            }
            dlina = dlina - 1;
        }
    }

    return slovo;
 }

int main(int arc, char *argv[])
{

    string slovo;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    cout << "Введите фразу на проверку: \n";
    getline(cin,slovo);
    cout << "Ваша фраза - " << slovo << "\n";

    transform(slovo.begin(), slovo.end(), slovo.begin(), tolower);
    slovo=np(slovo);
    int dlina=slovo.size();

    cout << "Измененная фраза - " << slovo << "\n";
    cout << "Длина - " << dlina << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i != dlina-1; i++)
    {
        if (slovo[i] != slovo[(dlina-1) - i])
        {
            cout << "Слово не то самое\n";
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "Слово то самое\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Проблему можно решить, просто введя глобальную переменную, но ее использование мне не очень нравится.

Comment: О каком "удалении пробелов" вы ведете речь? Ваш код просто занимается копированием каких-то символов в строке с одного места на другое. Ни о каком удалении пока речи не идет. Откуда ваша строка может узнать, что вы хотели что-то "удалить"? Каким образом вы собрались решать эту проблему "введением глобальной перменной" тоже в упор не ясно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите, то укоротить `string` до нужной длины можно с помощью

```
s.resize(n);
```

где `n` - новая длина.

Можно и удлинить :) Если нужно удлинять конкретным символом - укажите его в качестве второго аргумента.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы уже используете стандартные алгоритмы, то следует быть последовательным, и использовать алгоритмы вместо циклов, где это разумно.

Чтобы удалить из строки пробелы, то используется следующая общепринятая идиома

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

//...

slovo.erase(std::remove_if(slovo.begin(), slovo.end(), ::isspace), s.end());
```

Чтобы проверить, является ли строка палиндромом, то достаточно еще включить два вызова алгоритмов

```
std::transform(slovo.begin(), slovo.end(), slovo.begin(), ::tolower);

if (std::equal(slovo.begin(), std::next(slovo.begin(), slovo.size() / 2), slovo.rbegin()) )
{
    //...
}
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::string s;
        //std::string s("Ab b cB b a");

        std::cout << "Enter a sentence (Enter - exit): ";

        if ( not std::getline( std::cin, s ) or s.empty() ) break;

        s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isspace), s.end());
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);

        if (std::equal(s.begin(), std::next(s.begin(), s.size() / 2), s.rbegin()) )
        {
            std::cout << "The sentence is a palindrome" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "The sentence is not a palindromee" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может выглядеть как

```
Enter a sentence (Enter - exit): Ab b cB b a
The sentence is a palindrome
Enter a sentence (Enter - exit): Ab b CcB b a
The sentence is a palindrome
Enter a sentence (Enter - exit): Ab b CdB b 
The sentence is not a palindromee
Enter a sentence (Enter - exit):
```